# Check if numeric is reserved in App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to implement a deleted key detection for app engine if possible without any extra entities/markers being stored upon deletion, so I can show 404 or 410 response accordingly.

AFAIK new entity key numeric id's are assigned without particular order (at least a simple one), but they are of course reserved/allocated and never implicitly reused for new entities.

So is there a way to check if a particular key was previously allocated, but entity stored under this key was since deleted?

I do not care if a key was [manually allocated](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_ids) and never used to store any data, I'll treat it as deleted.

Comment: You can detect it, if you generate your own keys. If the key is based on a datetime stamp en does not exist anymore, it was previously allocated.

Comment: You can just try to get the entity and if `None` is returned, you show the response you prefer.

Comment: Thanos Makris, when entity was never there I'll also get None ;P.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to determine if a key has already been allocated.

You mention that you'll treat allocated but unused keys as deleted, but note that this will result in returning the wrong status code in these cases - including in the potential situation where a key is allocated and later used: you'll mistakenly report it as deleted until it's first used.

Comment: :( …how does GAE determine the next free key? Is it possible to make an API function that will check that a key was allocated? As for the false positive, it's a remote possibility, since if I manually allocate a key is't immediately or never used.

Comment: You can't invent your own API functions - only use those that are already there, and none of them provide this functionality. If you want to provide status tracking for deleted pages, you'll have to do it by storing your own state.

Comment: I know I cant on my own. I'm asking if is possible for app engine team to easily do it — meaning is there a point in making a feature request, or is this some very internal thing that would be hard to expose in the APIs and therefore there is no point in creating a feature request ;)